# chromedriver on centos 6.5 can not run

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, centos, selenium-chromedriver

1. My os is centos6.5
2. Download chrome27 old version and can run succeeded google-chrome 
   (google-chrome:8623): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: )
3. Download chromedriver 2.10 version
4. By https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=361 setup chromedriver

and  run chromedriver (./chromedriver), but show:

```
/opt/google/chrome/google-chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/google/chrome/google-chromedriver)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Update your OS to CentOS 6.6 at least or latest CentOS 7.x. Setup /etc/yum.repos.d with the correct file as mentioned here. It'll work. For CentOS 6.5, it's not supported I guess. http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just this error -> "Gtk: cannot open display" Which means it can not find display attached with device so if you have connected display you can export its address. generally it will be 0.0 So your command will be like "export DISPLAY=:0.0" if doesn't work try changing 0.0 to 0 then it can find the display and then it will start on GUI.